# Execute JavaScript in WordPress Hook

Tags: hooks, javascript, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

I want to execute a JavaScript code when someone place order on my Woocommerce site i googled and find this action hook `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'function_name',  1, 1  );` then in my callback function i did this `echo "<script>alert('Working?')<script>";` but this is not alerting why?? 
I want to execute a code a soon as order successfully placed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that. Cause in browser JavaScript works on DOM. And this `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` hook will be fired before the DOM loads. So there is no way you can execute this code on firing this hook.

Now there are two solutions I got-

1. Make it Ajaxified. So you don't need to reload the DOM and you can execute JavaScript on the DOM.
2. Second solution is relatively easy but not full proof. As far I understood there should be button by pressing that the order should be processed, right? So you can track this button activity and alert on this activity.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to put your alert inside an `onload` or a function for it to fire on echo from PHP. I believe alert() needs to be triggered by a function, `onload`, `select`, `click` etc.

You place a function with the alert in your header and then in the footer, call that function. The alert would only fire when a variable is set to `true`. You then echo `true` or `false` to that variable with PHP.

In your page header

```
var value = "<?php echo $value; ?>";`

function checkMe() {
   if("true" === value) {
     alert('something');
   }
}
```

after that, inside the footer of the page
`checkMe();`

or even put it as the body tag `onload` function.

```
<body onload="checkMe()">
```

That should do the trick. With the call in the footer, your page will load before the alert, with the body onload it will beat your page to the punch. I usually put confirm() in the body onload if needed for displaying content and alert() in the footer for status box display. Your call on your preference though.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's safe to use the hook ['woocommerce_thankyou'](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/71d0702523bcc365403dd3b84b945da5218d88b4/templates/checkout/thankyou.php#L74) in your case.
It's triggered on the "Order Received" page.